# Динамическое добавление и обработка на js jqeury

Tags: jquery

есть обычный див на нём есть спан на который при нажатии добавляется точно такой же блок
клик и добавление блока идёт динамически через $('body').on('click','.memadd',function(){});
всё работает но с багом, при одно нажатии добавляется как надо такой же блок
при новом нажатии на добавленный блок добавляется уже 2 блока, чтото я не так делаю наверное?

Comment: да явно что то не то делаете, но для помощи вам надо показать ваш полный код

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6d79dv8L/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы выполняете код

```
$('body').on('click','.memadd',function(){...});
```

больше одного раза.

*Update*

Пардон, дело оказалось в другом.

```
$(".memadd").after(...);
```

Добавляет новый html после каждого элементa с классом `memadd`. Используйте

```
$(".memadd").last().after(...);
```

Comment: а можно как то сделать чтобы его можно было выполнять больше одного раза? ) https://jsfiddle.net/6d79dv8L/1/

Comment: спасибо вам добрый человек